# Accessing view through activity

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

i cannot access my view script through my activity. what i want to do it:

Activity:

```
protected void callViewScriptFunction()
    {
        GameView.somefunction();
    }
```

GameView:

```
protected void somefunction();
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: change the visibility of someFunction() from **protected** to **public**

Comment: Still cant access anything out of my GameView Script

Comment: Can you provide more code because there are some parts missing here such as if you have created Objects or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create an instance of `GameView` to access it:

```
GameView myView = new GameView();
myView.somefunction();
```

or you can make a static method in `GameView`

```
protected static void somefunction(){
//do something
}
```

then access it anywhere statically `GameView.somefunction()`